# Configure automake to target assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, autotools, automake

Is it possible to configure automake to generate a Makefile which, in addition to building the .o files and linked binary, also has targets for %.s?  I want to be able to review the compiler output in a text format without having to invoke binutils on the .o files.

Specifically, if I have `main.c` as a source file, I want to be able to run `make main.s`.  The desired recipe would be the same as that for `main.o`, but using `CC1 := $(CC) -S`.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/196691).

You want to be able make the intermediate assembly file `foo.s`, where
the source file `foo.c` is one of the sources in an autotooled project, using
a makefile that is generated by the project's `./configure` script. You
assume that to do this you must do something to the automake inputs -
the `Makefile.am`s? - that will cause `./configure` to generate Makefiles
that include assembly targets `*.s` matching all object targets `*.o`.

Well you could, but then your project would not be a regular autotooled
project as usually distributed, and there is no need to make it irregular
to get what you want.

The GCC option [`-save-temps`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#Developer-Options)
exists to let developers see the intermediate files of compilation - the preprocessor
output, the assembly.

```
$ gcc -c -o foo.o foo.c
```

outputs `foo.o`

```
$ gcc -save-temps -c -o foo.o foo.c
```

outputs:

```
foo.o
foo.i   # preprocessed source
foo.s   # assembly
```

As I expect you know, GNU Make receives compiler options from the make-variable
`CFLAGS`, and automake respects this convention, independently of and in addition to any compiler
options prescribed by the project's autotooling. So, if you would otherwise generate
makefiles with:

```
$ ./configure ...
```

then, to add `-save-temps` to the C compiler options, generate makefiles instead
with:

```
$ ./configure CFLAGS=-save-temps ...
```

And if you are already using `CFLAGS`, e.g.

```
$ ./configure CFLAGS="-g -O0" ...
```

then append `-save-temps`:

```
$ ./configure CFLAGS="-g -O0 -save-temps" ...
```

Then,

```
$ make main.o
```

will make `main.o`, `main.i` and `main.s` up-to-date.

To disable `-save-temps`, of course, rerun `./configure`, removing it from
the `CFLAGS`.

If the project involves C++ compilation, then `CXXFLAGS` affects the C++
compiler in the same way that `CFLAGS` affects the C compiler. Note that
the generated preprocessed C++ sources will be called `*.ii`, not `*.i`.

With `-save-temps` enabled, `make clean` will *not* delete the `*.i` and `*.s`
files. You may not care, since compilation will always clobber them. If you
do care, you may take advantage of automake's standard phony target `clean-local`,
which is supported to let an autotooling maintainer extend the behaviour of
`clean`. Add the following recipe to the `Makefile.am` of each source directory
in the project:

```
clean-local:
    $(RM) *.i *.ii *.s
```

Then update the autotooling and regenerate Makefiles:

```
$ autoreconf
$ ./configure ...
```

Comment: Yup, `-save-temps` is a better way to go about this than baking the `.s` step into the build system.  Or as a one-off, copy the build command from a build log and run it manually from the right directory, with `-S -o- | less` at the end of the command line.  (And maybe other options to make the asm more human-readable: [How to remove “noise” from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)

Answer (score 1):

While the `COMPILE` variable in the generated `Makefile.in` is technically an internal detail, and this solution relies on the compiler to understand `-c -S`, adding:

```
.c.s:
        $(COMPILE) -c -S $<
```

to the `Makefile.am` has worked for as long as I've been using the autotools. It might also be convenient to add:

```
clean-local:
        rm -f *.s
```

I find this useful in development to have a look at the assembly output for specific `configure` and `CC`, `CFLAGS` options.

The `COMPILE` variable will be defined as something like:

```
COMPILE = $(CC) $(DEFS) $(DEFAULT_INCLUDES) $(INCLUDES) $(AM_CPPFLAGS) \
        $(CPPFLAGS) $(AM_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
```

Similarly, for C++ source we have:

```
.cc.s:
        $(CXXCOMPILE) -c -S $<
```

Comment: This is more convenient than `rm foo.o` / `make`, then copy / paste the compiler command line and edit it manually?  (With `-S -o- | less` at the end, so it pipes into a pager).  You do have to `cd` into the right directory, and if the build system doesn't spew the full command lines you have to go digging, but still it's what I usually do.